# Chrome Developer Tools throwing errors with Xperia inspector

Tags: google-chrome, drivers, android, web-development, mobile-phone

We have a number of android devices which we develop web apps for.

When we are developing for Chrome mobile, we fire up the Developer Mode and start inspecting the webpages for the devices. Once all the drivers and RSA keys have been accepted, we are able to see all the devices in chrome://inspect/#devices.

When clicking inspect, the chrome developer tools comes up and we are able to interact with the webpages elements and javascript. << All this is normal..

Except for the Sony Xperia Z1. When I bring up the Developer tool, it is blank. The drivers are fine since I would not have been able to get this far if they had not been, but just in case, I got them again. Still blank. I then did the crazy thing of bringing up the Developers tool page for the Developers tool. (Yeah, this is getting deep).

I was presented with some errors. I have never seen the Dev tool for the Dev tool show errors before and I don't even think I can do anything about them.. but I was hoping someone might be able to suggest what is wrong.. I am presuming it is something to do with the phone and again prob out of my control, but there may be some drivers that WILL do what we need and I just can't find them. The Output for the Dev tool Dev tool is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<InspectorFrontendHost> has no method 'zoomFactor' inspector.js:9162
Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest chrome-devtools://devtools/remote/serve_rev/@170502/170502.manifest devtools.html:1
Application Cache Checking event devtools.html:1
Application Cache NoUpdate event devtools.html:1
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'setAttachedWindow'
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'setDockSide' VM161:1
```

I have tried searching for some of these terms on Google, but very little directly related.
Any help would be greatful.